# react render using map on Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to build a page that shows the weather in all the locations mentioned in a list.

I want to render a card for each location and sort the cards next to each other so every row will contain 5 location cards [][][][][],
currently, it renders only one under the other in a column:
how can I solve this?

(weather.favoritesWeather is a list that contains all the data which  needs).

```
const FavoriteWeatherCards = weather.favoritesWeather.map(
    (favoriteLocation) => (
      <div>
        <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
          <Col md={3} >
            <SmallConditionsCard data={favoriteLocation} />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    )
  );



  return <div>
      {FavoriteWeatherCards}
      </div>;
};
```

code :

```
const SmallConditionsCard = ({data}) => {
  const { location, weather } = data;
  let history = useHistory();

  const handleClick = () => {
    history.push('/');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Card>
        <CardHeader
          sx={{ background: 'ghostwhite' }}
          title={
            <Typography align="center" variant="h5">
              {location.name}
            </Typography>
          }
        />
        <CardContent sx={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
          <WeatherIcon
            number={weather[0].WeatherIcon}
            xs={12}
            sx={{ maxHeight: 200, maxWidth: 200 }}
          />
          <Typography variant="h6">{weather[0].WeatherText}</Typography>
          <Typography variant="p">
            {formatTemp(weather[0].Temperature.Metric.Value, celcius)}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions>
          <Button size="small" onClick={handleClick}>Learn More </Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};
```

this is the result now: [image]

Comment: What are you using for your grid? Custom styles? Material UI? This should be an issue with your CSS but not sure the styles that Row and Column components have

Comment: @JorgeCordero the Row and Col are from react-bootstarp . but u used materialUi for most of the project. 
if you can show me how to do it in MUI that would be a huge help

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react-bootstrap you need your container

```
const FavoriteWeatherCards = weather.favoritesWeather.map(
    (favoriteLocation) => (
        <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
          <Col>
            <SmallConditionsCard data={favoriteLocation} />
          </Col>
        </Row>
    )
  );



  return <Container>
      {FavoriteWeatherCards}
      </Container>;
};
```

In case that you want to render something using material UI grid could be something like this

```
const FavoriteWeatherCards = weather.favoritesWeather.map(
    (favoriteLocation) => (
      <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Item>
            <SmallConditionsCard data={favoriteLocation} />
          </item>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    )
  );



  return <Grid container spacing={2}>
      {FavoriteWeatherCards}
      </grid>;
};
```